# How to: javascript fade in fade out text

Tags: javascript, fadein, fadeout

First of all: I looked through other posts on stackoverflow and none of them had the information I was looking for.

Second: I'm new to programming ;)

I want to have a div on my website that fades in and fades out text. I've seen this on a few web sites and am pretty sure it is javaScript using the jQuery library.

Does anyone know of a good tutorial, or can tell me how to accomplish this?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065273/fade-in-out-text-loop-jquery They have replied with a fiddle that might answer your question if you don't want to use a plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/n4mKw/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go :)

http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

Click on the effects you want, there are demos you can click around and copy the code from.

Another good one is [Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/). There are bunch of demos there too.

Answer (score 3):

i just gave an answer on another question:

[Using CSS for fade-in effect on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679567/using-css-for-fade-in-effect-on-page-load/16188533#16188533)

does this answer your question?