# Using CSS for a fade-in effect on page load

Tags: css, css-transitions, opacity

Can CSS transitions be used to allow a text paragraph to fade-in on page load?

I really like how it looked on [http://dotmailapp.com/](http://web.archive.org/web/20120728071954/http://www.dotmailapp.com/) and would love to use a similar effect using CSS. The domain has since been purchased and no longer has the effect mentioned. An archived copy can be viewed [on the Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20120728071954/http://www.dotmailapp.com/).

#### Illustration

Having this markup:

```html
<div id="test">
    <p>​This is a test</p>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

With the following CSS rule:

```css
#test p {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
}​
```

How can the transition be triggered on load?

Comment: You may want to read this: http://bavotasan.com/2011/a-simple-fade-with-css3/

Comment: Or this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/toggle-visibility-when-hiding-elements/

Answer (score 1118, accepted):

### Method 1:

If you are looking for a self-invoking transition then you should use [CSS 3 Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation). They aren't supported either, but this is exactly the kind of thing they were made for.

#### CSS

```css
#test p {
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;

    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

#### Demo

- http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/VV2ek/

#### Browser Support

All modern browsers and Internet Explorer 10 (and later): http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

### Method 2:

Alternatively, you can use jQuery (or plain JavaScript; see the third code block) to change the class on load:

#### jQuery

```js
$("#test p").addClass("load");​
```

#### CSS

```css
#test p {
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 21px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    text-align: center;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
       -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
        -ms-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
         -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
            transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
}

#test p.load {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

#### Plain JavaScript (not in the demo)

```js
document.getElementById("test").children[0].className += " load";
```

#### Demo

- http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/a9dnW/

#### Browser Support

All modern browsers and Internet Explorer 10 (and later): http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions

### Method 3:

Or, you can use the method that *.Mail* uses:

#### jQuery

```js
$("#test p").delay(1000).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 700);​
```

#### CSS

```css
#test p {
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 21px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

#### Demo

- http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/a9dnW/3/

#### Browser Support

**jQuery 1.x**: All modern browsers and Internet Explorer 6 (and later): http://jquery.com/browser-support/

**jQuery 2.x**: All modern browsers and Internet Explorer 9 (and later): http://jquery.com/browser-support/

This method is the most cross-compatible as the target browser does not need to support CSS 3 transitions *or* animations.

Comment: CSS3 Animation is supported just fine by every modern browser around. Of course, IE is not a modern browser.

Comment: Yes, but what if you want/need to be backwards compatible to IE6? In that case I think that jQuery is the best option. But, the asker wants it in CSS so I posted it as an alternative.

Comment: In addition (not tested) you should be able to use the transition property without jQuery to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Changed your fiddle to a bulge bounce - (and **Webkit only** ) http://jsfiddle.net/OMS_/GcWt7/

Comment: Isn't it best to set the initial opacity to 0 in javascript? That way if the user has javascript disabled the element is just there instead of never appearing.

Comment: @Jonathan You're right, that should definitely be changed.  Although I should, most of the time I don't think about how things are for javascript-disabled users, it's all cross-browser and responsive.     I don't have time right now, but I'll see if I can update it later.

Comment: @A.M.K I tried doing "fix" that just in the javascript but didn't manage to, so in the end I created a separate css file with `opacity: 1 !important;` and put in a `<noscript>` element.

Comment: Brilliant answer!
How hard is to apply the animation via `$("#test p").addClass("load");​` multiple times? Doing `$("#test p").removeClass('load').addClass("load");​` doesn't do the job since the animation has already stopped. Can I trigger a restart from JavaScript?

Comment: @serbanghita I haven't had to deal with that recently, but if I remember correctly you have to trigger a repaint before calling `addClass`.  You should be able to do that by querying a property like `outerWidth`.  But, since the method uses transitions you'll also need to remove them before removing the class and then reattach them before adding it back.

Comment: NOTE - for moz-keyframes you need to write it as  @--moz-keyframes

Comment: How would you implement the "falling" effect into this? Where the fading-in image looks like it's falling while it fades in?

Comment: @Juniper747 You could do that a number of ways. The first ones to come to mind are to move the element via transformations (the best for animations) or adjust the background position.

Comment: CSS3 is the best of all, no need for frameworks and fully compatible, besides, It's like a little absurd to be worried about IE6 when less than 5% of the market share uses IE 6,7,8,9 or whatever...

Comment: This needs a 2020 update. Is all of that CSS in Method 1 really still necessary?

Comment: Never mind, I just read your comments in the code. I suppose all that's realistically needed nowadays is the non-prefixed `animation` for all browsers?

Answer (score 37):

You can use the `onload=""` HTML attribute and use JavaScript to adjust the opacity style of your element.

Leave your CSS as you proposed. Edit your HTML code to:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById(test).style.opacity='1'">
    <div id="test">
        <p>​This is a test</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

**This also works to fade-in the complete page when finished loading:**

HTML:

```
<body onload="document.body.style.opacity='1'">
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{ 
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 2s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s; /* Safari */
}
```

Check the [W3Schools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3Schools) website: [transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) and an article for [changing styles with JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp).

Comment: Great answer. Alternatively I guess you can set the onload directly on the element. Like `<div id="test" onload="this.style.opacity='1'">`. Not sure if it means the event is triggered before the entire body is loaded though.

Answer (score 5):

In response to @A.M.K's question about how to do transitions without jQuery. A very simple example I threw together. If I had time to think this through some more, I might be able to eliminate the JavaScript code altogether:

```
<style>
    body {
        background-color: red;
        transition: background-color 2s ease-in;
    }
</style>

<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#00f';
    }
</script>

<body>
    <p>test</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Another method is to use JS's [Web Animations API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API) in combination with CSS.

Example

```
async function moveToPosition(el, durationInMs) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const animation = el.animate([{
        opacity: '0'
      },
      {
        transform: `translateY(${el.getBoundingClientRect().top}px)`
      },
    ], {
      duration: durationInMs,
      easing: 'ease-in',
      iterations: 1,
      direction: 'normal',
      fill: 'forwards',
      delay: 0,
      endDelay: 0
    });
    animation.onfinish = () => resolve();
  });
}

async function fadeIn(el, durationInMs) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const animation = el.animate([{
        opacity: '0'
      },
      {
        opacity: '0.5',
        offset: 0.5
      },
      {
        opacity: '1',
        offset: 1
      }
    ], {
      duration: durationInMs,
      easing: 'linear',
      iterations: 1,
      direction: 'normal',
      fill: 'forwards',
      delay: 0,
      endDelay: 0
    });
    animation.onfinish = () => resolve();
  });
}

async function fadeInSections() {
  for (const section of document.getElementsByTagName('section')) {
    await fadeIn(section, 200);
  }
}

window.addEventListener('load', async() => {
  await moveToPosition(document.getElementById('headerContent'), 500);
  await fadeInSections();
  await fadeIn(document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0], 200);
});
```

```js
async function moveToPosition(el, durationInMs) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const animation = el.animate([{
        opacity: '0'
      },
      {
        transform: `translateY(${el.getBoundingClientRect().top}px)`
      },
    ], {
      duration: durationInMs,
      easing: 'ease-in',
      iterations: 1,
      direction: 'normal',
      fill: 'forwards',
      delay: 0,
      endDelay: 0
    });
    animation.onfinish = () => resolve();
  });
}

async function fadeIn(el, durationInMs) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const animation = el.animate([{
        opacity: '0'
      },
      {
        opacity: '0.5',
        offset: 0.5
      },
      {
        opacity: '1',
        offset: 1
      }
    ], {
      duration: durationInMs,
      easing: 'linear',
      iterations: 1,
      direction: 'normal',
      fill: 'forwards',
      delay: 0,
      endDelay: 0
    });
    animation.onfinish = () => resolve();
  });
}

async function fadeInSections() {
  for (const section of document.getElementsByTagName('section')) {
    await fadeIn(section, 200);
  }
}

window.addEventListener('load', async() => {
  await moveToPosition(document.getElementById('headerContent'), 500);
  await fadeInSections();
  await fadeIn(document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0], 200);
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  height: 20%;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.leading-none {
  line-height: 1;
}

.leading-3 {
  line-height: .75rem;
}

.leading-2 {
  line-height: .25rem;
}

.bg-black {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.bg-gray-50 {
  background-color: rgba(249, 250, 251, 1);
}

.pt-12 {
  padding-top: 3rem;
}

.pt-2 {
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
}

.text-lightGray {
  color: lightGray;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  /* or inline-flex */
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container section {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.opacity-0 {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-snowpack-app" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/syles/index.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header class="bg-gray-50">
    <div id="headerContent">
      <h1 class="text-center leading-none pt-2 leading-2">Hello</h1>
      <p class="text-center leading-2"><i>Ipsum lipmsum emus tiris mism</i></p>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <section class="opacity-0">
      <h2 class="text-center"><i>ipsum 1</i></h2>
      <p>Cras purus ante, dictum non ultricies eu, dapibus non tellus. Nam et ipsum nec nunc vestibulum efficitur nec nec magna. Proin sodales ex et finibus congue</p>
    </section>
    <section class="opacity-0">
      <h2 class="text-center"><i>ipsum 2</i></h2>
      <p>Cras purus ante, dictum non ultricies eu, dapibus non tellus. Nam et ipsum nec nunc vestibulum efficitur nec nec magna. Proin sodales ex et finibus congue</p>
    </section>

    <section class="opacity-0">
      <h2 class="text-center"><i>ipsum 3</i></h2>
      <p>Cras purus ante, dictum non ultricies eu, dapibus non tellus. Nam et ipsum nec nunc vestibulum efficitur nec nec magna. Proin sodales ex et finibus congue</p>
    </section>
  </div>
  <footer class="opacity-0">
    <h1 class="text-center leading-3 text-lightGray"><i>dictum non ultricies eu, dapibus non tellus</i></h1>
    <p class="text-center leading-3"><i>Ipsum lipmsum emus tiris mism</i></p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```