# How can I place text in the middle of vertical align?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When it shows comment, it won't show the comment in the middle of vertical-align.
How can I make it shown in the middle of vertical-align?

This is current output.  I want it right in the middle of vertical-align.

[image]

**Javascript**

```
function showComments(time){
    var foundComments = findComments(time);
    $.each(foundComments,function(i,comment){
        $commentContainer.animate({"marginLeft":"400px","opacity":".0"}, 600);
        setComment(comment.message);
        $commentContainer.animate({"marginLeft":"0px","opacity":"1"}, 600);
    });
};
```

**CSS**

```
div.newsticker{
    border:1px solid #666666;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}

.newsticker p{
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="newsticker"> 
    </div>
```

Comment: are you looking to have your text appear in center of the div?

Answer (score 1):

If its a single line. set the line height to the height of the `div.newsticker` eg 100px.

For example 
`font: 16px/100px 'arial', sans-serif`

Comment: it could be either single or double. that's the problem

Answer (score 1):

Just update below CSS3 rule to use "table-cell" and "vertical-align" as below:

```
div.newsticker{
    border:1px solid #666666;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Also, you need to avoid position:absolute;

```
.newsticker p{
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. it looks right. But the problem is that I use animation. and your code makes it look different animation

Comment: @HUSTEN - Can you please post your code via jsfiddle to help you with animation too?

Comment: I made DEMO! Please check http://jsfiddle.net/azHVv/  It won't be shown on the middle of vertical align!!

Comment: @HUSTEN - Please refer this post, and you can try using CSS based animations if you are ok for morden browser support only, [Sample Animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679567/using-css-for-fade-in-effect-on-page-load)

Comment: @HUSTEN - You need to wrap everything inside a div to avoid that animation error.

Answer (score 1):

Try a div with `display:table`  and then a div within with a `display: table-cell` where you want the text.  That should vertical align,  JS Fiddle is down, so I can't show you an example.

```
div.newsticker{
    border:1px solid #666666;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    display: table;
}

.newsticker p{
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;   
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. it looks right. But the problem is that I use animation. and your code makes it look different animation

Comment: I made DEMO! Please check http://jsfiddle.net/azHVv/  It won't be shown on the middle of vertical align!!

Comment: This is the move how I want it http://jsfiddle.net/azHVv/6/  I applied your code but now the move became just like this http://jsfiddle.net/azHVv/7/  see the difference? second one looks strange

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
<span class="newsticker"> 
</span></div>



div {
border: 1px solid black;
}
span.newsticker {
border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.newsticker p {
margin: 50px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/azHVv/22/

Comment: I made DEMO! Please check http://jsfiddle.net/azHVv/  It won't be shown on the middle of vertical align!!