# How can I create a fade in/fade out effect using only CSS?

Tags: css

I want to do fade in and fade out effects using only CSS. If I move or hover over one div element,  I then need to call another DIV to fade in, snd then it should fade out agsin when the mouse leaves. DOM element calling and effect should be in `CSS` or `CSS3`. I can't use javascript and Jquery.

```
<style> 
#b
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 35px;
    padding: 30px 0px;
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 10px 2px;
    opacity:0;
    color: white;
    font: 20px bold;
}
#a
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    background: rgb(156, 155, 155);
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 35px;
    padding: 30px 0px;
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 10px 2px;
    color: white;
    font: 20px bold;
}

#a:hover + #b { 
    animation:myfirst 1s;
    -webkit-animation:first 1s;
    opacity:1;
                }

@keyframes first
{
from {opacity:0.1;}
to {opacity:1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes first 
{
from {opacity:0.1}
to {opacity:1;}
}

</style>

<div id="a">Hover</div>
<div id="b">show</div>
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679567/using-css-for-fade-in-effect-on-page-load

Comment: i have edited my code check once again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily achieve that with `opacity` and the `adjacent sibling combinator`.

Check out the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dY3bS/1/) for a vendor prefixed version.

```
#container + div {
    transition: opacity .25s; 
    opacity: 0;
}

#container:hover + div {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[Transition browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions)

[Adjacent sibling combinator (+ selector) documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators)