# When are CSS transitions fired?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I'd like to fade a page in. It should fade in as soon as possible i.e. not wait for images to load.

I have an html page with

```
<div class="content">
   text, images
</div>
```

I have css like

```
.content{
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

and just above the `</body>` I have

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".content").css("opacity",1);
});
```

but it feels like a long time loading if a page has lots of images. I thought this was supposed to fire as soon as the DOM is written to the browser?

I tried removing document ready but it was the same. So I was wondering, when is the CSS transition triggered? Is it later than document ready?

The effect I'm going for is for pages to fade up.

Comment: Have you tried a script at the end of the body that executes your jquery?

Comment: It's a great question!  This will take some testing..  Very curious to see responses and answers to this one!

Comment: This is a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679567/using-css-for-fade-in-effect-on-page-load that may help in answering.

Answer (score 1):

How about using animate function instead of css like this?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".content").delay(1).animate({opacity:1});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#starting) transition starts when some [style changed event](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#style-change-event) is called (as I see it is a browser specific stuff). The problem is we can't be sure it is called before DOM fully loaded:

> Since this specification does not define when a style change event
>   occurs, and thus what changes to computed values are considered
>   simultaneous, authors should be aware that changing any of the
>   transition properties a small amount of time after making a change
>   that might transition can result in behavior that varies between
>   implementations, since the changes might be considered simultaneous in
>   some implementations but not others.

I don't think that this event would be raised before DOM is loaded.

Accroding to this I think if you need transitions before DOM is loaded then it's better to use jQuery to animate your elements as [C-link suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21153479/2706794). If it is ok to start transitions after use this question: [Using CSS for fade-in effect on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679567/using-css-for-fade-in-effect-on-page-load)