# CSS3, HTML5, Javascript: How to make divs fade in?

Tags: html, css

I have a small problem that I'm really scratching my head as to how to implement. I would like to know how to make a dynamically generated div fade in only. The div(s) are dynamically generated by Javascript code. How do I make it so that the div fades in onto the page? I cannot use jQuery or .innerHTML().

Comment: Why you cant use **jQuery**?: $('.yourElement').fadeIn();

Comment: Adrian, the poster SPECIFICALLY said NO JQUERY!

Comment: It's an exercise, Adrian.

Comment: Diodeus, thanks, but that's for hovering. The divs are dynamically generated by javascript, but I want the divs to be faded in.

Comment: If it's an exercise, what have you tried? You can look at jquery code for inspiration https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js

Comment: I found this guys! And it works perfectly for me! :D

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679567/using-css-for-fade-in-effect-on-page-load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a rule in your stylesheet with a selector that matches the div and which sets a `transition` property.
2. Create another rule that matches the div if it is a member of an additional class and style it to be invisible (`opacity` is a good property to use for this).
3. Create the div
4. Add the class to the div
5. Add the div to the document
6. With a minimal `setTimeout` (to allow the browser to repaint the document with the div added), remove the class

Answer (score 1):

**CSS**:

```
#fade-in-div{
    transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

**JS**

```
//generate new div
document.write("<div id='fade-in-div'>New Div!</div>");

//make opacity = 1. This should take 1 second to make (1s fade).
document.getElementById("fade-in-div").style.opacity = 1; //this should take 1 second
```

Comment: I'm not hovering, the div is generated by javascript. I want the div to fade in when generated.