# fade-in Styles CSS not working properly in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, web, styles

My Code for showing divs with fade-in effect is as here

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }

.fade-in {
        opacity:0;  
        -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;  
        -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
        animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

        -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;  
        -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
        animation-fill-mode:forwards;

        -webkit-animation-duration:2s;
        -moz-animation-duration:2s;
        animation-duration:2s;

    }

.fade-in.one
{
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.7s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1.7s;
    animation-delay: 1.7s;
}
```

Then i am using that to a div which needs to fade in while loading.

```
<div  class="fade-in one">
<label>Message Box</label>
This box will show some messages
</div>
```

This code works fine in chrome and firefox as well, but in ie it is showing no animation.

Kindly help in fixing this problem. I have tried many changes in the code, and IE versions as well. But no joy. Please help ....

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

Comment: Try to use `0%` instead of `from` and `100%` instead of `to`

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679567/using-css-for-fade-in-effect-on-page-load