# Fade In doesn't work on IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am using this code to fade-in images when the page loads. Works fine in all browsers I have tested except from IE on Windows.

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }

.fade-in {opacity:0;-webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;-moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;-moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;animation-fill-mode:forwards;-webkit-animation-duration:1.5s;-moz-animation-duration:1.5s;animation-duration:1.5s;}

.fade-in.one {-webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;-moz-animation-delay: 0.3s;animation-delay: 0.3s;}
.fade-in.two {-webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;-moz-animation-delay:0.6s;animation-delay: 0.6s;}
.fade-in.three {-webkit-animation-delay: 0.9s;-moz-animation-delay: 0.9s;animation-delay: 0.9s;}
```

any ideas?

Comment: Is that for all versions of IE? What versions?

Comment: Transitions and Animations weren't supported [until IE 10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673530(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [this](https://graphicfusiondesign.com/design/creating-fancy-css3-fade-in-animations-on-page-load/) method and it has a warning for IE:

> Warning! This CSS3 code will only work on Firefox, Chrome, Safari and
>   maybe newer versions of IE (after version 9)
>
> Since IE9 doesn’t support css3 animations but does support opacity: 0;
>   property you will have to have ie9 load a separate ie9 css where you
>   have all your fade classes set to opacity: 1

If you are looking for alternative:

### Method 1:

If you are looking for a self-invoking transition then you should use [CSS3 Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation), they aren't supported as well but this is exactly the kind of thing they were made for.

#### CSS

```css
#test p {
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;

    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

#### Demo

- http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/VV2ek/

#### Browser Support

All modern browsers, IE 10+: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

### Method 2:

Alternatively, you can use jQuery (or plain JS, see third code block) to change the class on load:

#### jQuery

```js
$("#test p").addClass("load");​
```

#### CSS

```css
#test p {
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 21px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    text-align: center;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
       -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
        -ms-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
         -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
            transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
}

#test p.load {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

#### Plain JS (not in demo)

```js
document.getElementById("test").children[0].className += " load";
```

#### Demo

- http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/a9dnW/

#### Browser Support

All modern browsers, IE 10+: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions

### Method 3:

Or, you can use the method that *.Mail* uses:

#### jQuery

```js
$("#test p").delay(1000).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 700);​
```

#### CSS

```css
#test p {
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 21px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

#### Demo

- http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/a9dnW/3/

#### Browser Support

**jQuery 1.x**: All modern browsers, IE 6+: http://jquery.com/browser-support/

**jQuery 2.x**: All modern browsers, IE 9+: http://jquery.com/browser-support/

This method is the most cross-compatible as the target browser does not need to support CSS3 transitions *or* animations.

**[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679567/using-css-for-fade-in-effect-on-page-load)**

Comment: I am trying method 3 but it doesn't work for me. My HTML is: <figure class="effect-sarah fade-in one"> .. </figure>

Comment: Thanks, this works. But thing to remember is not to place it in media query; animation in media queries does not work in IE.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add the prefix `-ms-` like `-ms-animation-delay`.
Because you have just specify the prefix `-moz-` for `mozilla` and `-webkit-` for `chrome`.