# Input fields painted in delay if at all on IE 11

Tags: angular

I have the strangest problem on IE11. works well on other explorers.

The inputs just don't paint immidietly. they disapear and appear randomly. It's like IE takes ages to paint them or something.

I followed https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie but it still does not work.

angular/cli: 1.0.6
node: 6.10.1
os: win32 x64
angular/common: 4.2.2
angular/compiler: 4.2.2
angular/compiler-cli: 4.2.2
angular/core: 4.2.2
angular/forms: 4.2.2
angular/http: 4.2.2
angular/platform-browser: 4.2.2
angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.2.2
angular/router: 4.2.2
angular/cli: 1.0.6

This is my main code with the inputs that are painted in delay (if at all):

```
  <div *ngFor="let question of stage.questions" class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 section-padding"
        [class.fadeIn]="stage.discount == discountStage" [class.fadeOut]="stage.discount != discountStage" [class.none]="stage.none">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="padding:0px">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" style="padding:0px;font-weight:bold;min-height:50px;">
                    <div style="padding-top:10px;"><span>{{question.content}}</span> <span *ngIf="question.required" title="שדה חובה">*</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12" style="padding:0px;min-height:50px;">
              <div *ngIf="!question.multiAnswers && (question.type == 'input' || question.type == 'email') && stage.index == getCurrentStage()"
                        >
                      <input [id]="'calcq' + question.id" ng-attr-type="text" class="form-control" ng-attr-value="getText(question)"
                                (keyup)="handleKeyUp(question, $event);" (blur)="handleBlur(question, $event)" [class.disabled]="isDisabled(question)"
                             ng-attr-placeholder="getPlaceholder(question)" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                        <i class="fa fa-remove error-point" [class.none]="!question.requiredError" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" [title]="getRequiredText(question)"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-remove error-point" *ngIf="question.accept == 'number'" [class.none]="!question.acceptError" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="יש להזין מספר בלבד"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-remove error-point" *ngIf="question.accept == 'decimal'" [class.none]="!question.acceptError" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="יש להזין מספר בלבד"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-remove error-point" *ngIf="question.accept == 'alpha'" [class.none]="!question.acceptError" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="יש להזין אותיות בלבד"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-remove error-point" *ngIf="question.id == '1.0'" [class.none]="!question.emailError" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="יש להזין כתובת אימייל תקינה"></i>
                        <span>{{getText(question)}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: try remove `*ngIf` for all inputs and see if you get the performance issue. There might be some weird logic in that area.

Comment: The documentation that you linked to is for AngularJS. For the Angular documentation, see https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

Comment: @windmaomao tried it, same story

Comment: ANYONE ?????????

Comment: Maybe it's because fade-in and fade-out is not supported by all IE --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27239598/fade-in-doesnt-work-on-ie

Comment: adding: the fade-in is on the div wrapped around the input. Is this outer div visible? Are only the inputs gone?

Comment: I manage to fix it by just removing all the animations on IE !