# CSS color change in basic HTML document

Tags: html, css

Consider the following code:

```
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #CCC;
    }

    .con {
      background-color: #FFF;
      width: 80%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="con">
    [SITE CONTENT]
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

What I am trying to achieve is to have the content background in white color which takes `80%` of the screen width and will be in center.

Body background (`10%` right and `10%` left) will be of gray color. (`80%` of the center will be occupied by the content `div` with white background).

It is working fine. But most of the times when the page loads, (mostly when network is slow), initially the content also will appear in gray background and then it changes to white.

What is the best way to avoid this transition effect?

I am now thinking of the following options:

> a. Change color of body at the end using js
>
> b. Initially in [css](/questions/tagged/css), background color of body also be white and then
>   at the end of document, override css and make it gray.

But I am sure there is a better solution. Please help.

Comment: Please correct: .con{background-color:#FFF; width:80%; margin: 0 auto;}

Comment: corrected, was a typo sorry. my actual code is like this only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like this without using jQuery:

Set your html in `display: none;`. Then when your page is loaded changes to `display: block;` to show the html content.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var html = document.querySelector("html");
  html.setAttribute("style", "display: block");
}, 1000);
```

```css
html {
  display: none;
}
body {
  background-color: #CCC;
}
.con {
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="con">[SITE CONTENT]</div>
</body>
```

Another way is using jQuery library:

```js
$(function() // When the DOM is ready.
{
    $("html").css({
      "display": "block"
    });
});
```

```css
html {
  display: none;
}
body {
  background-color: #CCC;
}
.con {
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="con">[SITE CONTENT]</div>
</body>
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

What about this? Credits to [A.M.K](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11681331/4847766)

```
body {
  -moz-animation: fadein 4s;
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: fadein 4s;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-animation: fadein 4s;
  /* Opera */
  background-color: #ccc;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  to {
    background-color: #ccc;
    ;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
  /* Firefox */
  from {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  to {
    background-color: #ccc;
    ;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  from {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  to {
    background-color: #ccc;
    ;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadein {
  /* Opera */
  from {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  to {
    background-color: #ccc;
    ;
  }
}

.con {
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```