# How to convert a jQuery fade effect in CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I have the following code which is going to fade some images but I am interested if there is a way to handle this in CSS.

```
$("#top").stop(true, true).delay(0).fadeTo(fadeTime * 100, 0);
$("#back").stop(true, true).delay(0).fadeTo(fadeTime * 100, 1, function () {
    if (curLoop < loops) {
        if (curImg < imgNo) {
            prevImg = curImg
            curImg++
        } else {
            prevImg = imgNo
            curImg = 1;
            curLoop++console.log("LOOP");
        }

        document.getElementById("back").style.opacity = 0;

        document.getElementById("top").style.opacity = 1;

        document.getElementById("back").src = "frames/frame_" + curImg + ".jpg";
        document.getElementById("top").src = "frames/frame_" + prevImg + ".jpg";
    } else {
        console.log("STOPPED");
        window.clearInterval(myVarSTD);
    }

    if (!initialized) {
        myVarSTD = setInterval(function () {
            startAnimation()
        }, delay * 1000);
        initialized = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes with CSS3 ease.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679567/using-css-for-fade-in-effect-on-page-load

Comment: This is confiusing. You specificaly asked how to make your jquery animation into CSS and you accept a jquery answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't loop through image sources in a pure CSS animation but the below fade effect is possible with CSS3 animations. Here the front and back images are absolutely positioned and using `opacity` animation they are faded in and out in an infinite loop. I have used 2 `div` with `background-image` but you could do the same for `img` element also.

Refer inline comments within the snippet for more explanation of the animation's CSS code.

```css
.front,
.back {
  position: absolute; /* absolute positioning puts them one on top of other */
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  animation: fade-in-out 10s linear infinite; /* first is animation keyframe's name, second is the duration of the animation, third is timing function and fourth is iteration count */
}
.front {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/1);
}
.back {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/2);
  z-index: -1; /* keeps the element behind the front */
  animation-delay: 5s; /* delay is equal to half the animation duration because the back has to fade-in once the front has faded-out at 50% */
}
@keyframes fade-in-out { /* animation settings */
  0%, 100% {
    opacity: 1; /* at start and end, the image is visible */
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0; /* at the mid point of the animation, the image is invisible */
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class='front'></div>
<div class='back'></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. Your code capture some elements using `getElementById` as `back` and `top`.

You can use the following code to change CSS properties of those elements:

```
$('#back').css({'opacity':'1'});
```

Implemented in your code:

```
$("#top").stop(true, true).delay(0).fadeTo(fadeTime*100, 0);
            $("#back").stop(true, true).delay(0).fadeTo(fadeTime*100, 1, function(){
                if(curLoop<loops){
                    if(curImg<imgNo){
                        prevImg = curImg
                        curImg++
                    }else{
                        prevImg = imgNo
                        curImg = 1;
                        curLoop++
                        console.log("LOOP");
                    }               

    $('#back').css({'opacity':'0'});

    $('#top').css({'opacity':'1'});

                    document.getElementById("back").src = "frames/frame_"+curImg+".jpg";
                    document.getElementById("top").src = "frames/frame_"+prevImg+".jpg";            
                }else{
                    console.log("STOPPED");
                    window.clearInterval(myVarSTD);
                }

                if(!initialized){           
                    myVarSTD = setInterval(function(){startAnimation()},delay*1000);
                    initialized = true;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) is an awesome plugin which mimics jQuery's animation functions but in CSS. You get a much higher framerate using CSS too!