# Flow in text / Pop Out

Tags: html, css

What's the code to make a text, or a picture flow in on my website. A good example is this website: https://isephful.com/ As you can see, the icons pops out whenever you enter the website. I've tried looking at the HTML, without any luck, couldn't see what's used. Could someone please just tell me what code was used etc.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: Try this question for some hints http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679567/using-css-for-fade-in-effect-on-page-load

Comment: Thank you very much for that! It was what I was looking for!

Answer (score -1):

It's a matter of using jQuery method .animate. Making more advanced websites with only html and css will give you hard time.

Comment: I mean what ever it takes to make this work would be helpful.