# Can we use the fade out on a button which takes us to next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button which takes to another html.
But is there a way to fade out whole front page by clicking the button and take it to second page.
Now I can just fade out the front page by clicking anywhere but when I click the button it reloads to the new page without the fade effect.

Below is the code related to it:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="fade">
Some content
<a href="page2.html"><button>Click me</button></a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#fade").click(function(){
        $("#fade").fadeOut("slow");
    });
```

Thank you.

Comment: you need to use ajax to change the page without refresh or read the whole container of page2.html and put it in the div and fadeIn again

Comment: @Araz can you give me a working example using two different html pages please.

Comment: @Archer That solution uses Smoothstate.js which does use AJAX

Comment: There is a bunch of questions like this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679567/using-css-for-fade-in-effect-on-page-load

Comment: Lol.  That's not what I was looking for but found it and thought it was better suited.  Ah well :D

Comment: @Archer I tried using this but it doesn't have two different htmls, And I cannot change second html page to be part of the first html. It will be a lot to redo.

Comment: you can have a look into this jsfiddle.. https://jsfiddle.net/josangel555/y2m2ygvr/1/

Comment: Thank you but are the not div's on the same page ? @redflar3, that is something I am already achieving, I was looking for two different html pages like first page, index.html to page2.html, here the page reloads and it doesn't allow the fade out to happen.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0y50khxk maybe this would help a bit

Comment: @pritishvaidya no I tried this, but you can see when button is clicked it would directly reload to the second page without any effect.