# Fade on load doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, fade

So I found this solution [Using CSS for fade-in effect on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679567/using-css-for-fade-in-effect-on-page-load) And I've used Method 2 with raw JavaScript. Here's my code sample

**JavaScript**

```
var fadeOnLoad = function () {
  document.getElementById("wrapper").className += "load";
};
fadeOnLoad();
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
}

.load {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Link to the website where it doesn't work https://skidle.github.io/projects/weather

And this text is crossed out in Google Dev tools
[image]

Comment: `opacity: 1 !important;` ?  id selector has higher priority than class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to define

```
opacity: 1 !important;
```

id selector has higher priority than class

Here is a snippet with clear process logic. Element is invisible until body got loaded. As soon as event body onload fired, element gets `opacity: 1;`

```js
function fadeOnLoad() {
  document.getElementById("wrapper").className = "";
};
```

```css
#wrapper {
  transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
}

.not_loaded {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<body onload="fadeOnLoad()">
<div id="wrapper" class="not_loaded">text</div>
</body>
```

Comment: or refine your selector : `#wrapper.load{opacity:1;}`

Answer (score 1):

Add important to your class attribute.

```
.load{
      opcacity: 1 !important; //because you have id selector with opacity to 0.
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

As a good practice, **try to avoid using IDs for styling**.

---

Instead of defining the transition in the `#wrapper` selector, create a class containing the `transition` property like so:

```
.opacity-transition {
  transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
}
```

Once the transition ends, this class will not be needed any more and can be removed.

Create another class to initially hide the `#wrapper` element. When this class is removed it will trigger the transition.

```
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

**Code Snippet:**

```js
function fadeOnLoad() {
  //Cache the selector.
  var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
  console.log(wrapper.className);
  //Add event listener for transition end.
  wrapper.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
    //Remove the class which is not needed anymore.
    this.classList.remove("opacity-transition");
    console.log(this.className);
  });
  //Remove hidden class to start the transition.
  wrapper.classList.remove("hidden");

};
```

```css
.opacity-transition {
  transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
}
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<body onload="fadeOnLoad()">
  <div id="wrapper" class="opacity-transition hidden">
    text</div>
</body>
```

---

## [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/682q8g01/)