# .addClass and .delay is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I tried to use this solution [Using CSS for fade-in effect on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679567/using-css-for-fade-in-effect-on-page-load/11681331#11681331) at [this page](http://itisin.pigfarm.ca/resources/)

I put

```
<script type="text/javascript> 
$("#top).addClass("load");
</script>
```

​in my javascript but why it's not add load class when load. I also has been tried

```
<script type="text/javascript> 
$("#top").delay(1000).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 700);​
</script>
```

but still not worked. It's worked at JSFiddle but not at my site.

Please help me!

Thanks,

Adi

Comment: You're executing your code before the DOM is ready. Wrap your jQuery logic in a document.ready handler, eg: `$(function() { /* your code here ... */ });`

Comment: Also, you missed a closing quotation mark in `$("#top").addClass("load");`.

Comment: I think you need to include jquery .. you can take a look at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-jquery  and see the **Setting Up jQuery** section .. Additional .. you need to include jquery before doing your stuff or wrap your code in `$(document).ready(function(){  //code here })`

Comment: Thank you for the clue about wrap. I already found the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your answers friends. But this is the worked version

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".page-id-29 header#top").addClass("load");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Must trigger it like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $("#top").addClass("load");
       $("#top").delay(1000).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 700);​
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it's not worked in my site. The worked wrap is jQuery(document).ready(function($) { });

Comment: Okey try this jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       jQuery("#top").addClass("load");
       jQuery("#top").delay(1000).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 700);​
});