# PHP Show array one by one with interval in for loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have an array with 4 rows, I Want to show them one by one, But only one and with an Interval.

Like: 
Row1 show for 5secs -> Row2 show for 5secs -> Row3 show for 5secs -> Row4 show for 5secs

I tried this, but that is not working. It loads much time and than showing only one and doing nothing more.

```
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result) -1;
 for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) { 
    $random = rand(0, $count);
    echo json_encode($data[$random]);
    unset($data[$random]);
    $count -= 1;
    sleep(5);
}
```

Comment: $count -= 1 and  $i++  are in conflict  .. .. you should use another type of loop  .. try using a while (count($data)) > 0

Comment: If you want timed output you will need to look into the flush functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution could be to simply to deliver all the data in PHP to a javascript client, and have the client simply show the information using a simple `setTimeout` function or perhaps using CSS animation.

similar to this:

[Using CSS for fade-in effect on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679567/using-css-for-fade-in-effect-on-page-load)

or perhaps this:

https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-settimeout-function-examples/

that you can get rid of the PHP `sleep()` call.