# Blazor .Net + Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( )?

Tags: .net, .net-core, dispatcher, begininvoke, blazor

Is it possible to do the following using the new Blazor framework?

I have a page that displayed a list of people. The list is essentially a bindable list of Person objects.

**Desired Result**
I would like to show each person fade-in independently of each other.

For example: The 1st row starts fading in first. The Nth row person will be the last to fade in.

**What I tried**
I've tried a couple of things using Task.Delay() and tried to get Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() to work.

But now i am starting to think this is not possible without doing some kind of hack.

> Is this kind of effect even possible via Blazor? Is there a
>   Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() equivalent?

Comment: Dispatcher and Task.Delay are used in multi-threaded environments. Blazor is single-threaded in its current form. You would likely have to use some jquery or css to get your desired effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option, if your `Blazor` application is run on client-side, is to use a combination of `CSS3 animations` to fade in rows and a `Task.Delay` to add rows delayed.

I will give you an example based on the default `Blazor` (.NET core 3.0 preview 3) template.

Inspired by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679567/using-css-for-fade-in-effect-on-page-load) you could add the following `CSS class` to your **site.css** or some costom `CSS` file:

```
.fadein {
    -webkit-animation: fadein 1s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
    -moz-animation: fadein 1s; /* Firefox < 16 */
    -ms-animation: fadein 1s; /* Internet Explorer */
    -o-animation: fadein 1s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
    animation: fadein 1s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Now we will modify the **FetchData.razor** page, which by default shows a `HTML` table with some forecast info.

First we add a style class to the table rows `<tr>` as following:

```
@foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
{
    <tr class="fadein">
        <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
        <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
        <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
        <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Next we will change the type of the `forecasts` from an `array` to a `List`:

```
List<WeatherForecast> forecasts = new List<WeatherForecast>();
```

As a last step we replace the `forecasts` preparation in the `OnInitAsync` with the following call:

```
protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
{
    await FadeInItems();
}
```

and add the method for the delayed fading in:

```
private async Task FadeInItems()
{
    var items = await Http.GetJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("sample-data/weather.json");

    // don't forget to use the desired sorting / filtering on your collection
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        forecasts.Add(item);
        base.StateHasChanged();
        await Task.Delay(500);
    }
}
```

And this should be your result:
[image: fade in animation]

Based on this demo, you should now be able to apply this method to your `Person` model and individual razor page(s). Ofcourse the animation, delay and other things are just an example and can be customized.

Comment: Thanks. This is very very thorough! Where does base.StateHasChanged(); come from though?

Comment: Also, my async function is in the View Model. And the compiler is complaining that i cant directly await a Task without calling ConfigureAwait.

Comment: The `StateHasChanged()` signals Blazor to render the page using `WASM`, as the state has changed. You can call the async method in your ViewModel just replace the default `protected override void OnInit()` with `protected override Task OnInitAsync()` like in the above example.

Comment: Two ways to do that: either pass the base class of the page to the ViewModel or cleaner add an event `ViewModelChanged` to your ViewModel and let the page subscribe to it, calling StateHasChanged whenever the ViewModel changed. I am traveling right now, I can give you an example later on, invite me to a SO chat room to keep the comments shorts.

Comment: Hi Raul, i have everything compiling with debug outputs to verify the delayed adding of objects. Indeed they are behaving as i expect. However, the UI has all objects fading in at the same time. Any ideas? BTW - i had to do Task.Delay(500).ConfigureAwait(true)

Comment: In fact, i can see that the view's StateHasChanged is being invoked in a delayed fashion (as expected). But upon deeper analysis, I can see that the UI renders after all task.delays are done.

Comment: Oh. I think i found the issue. I am not running Blazor as client-side. Dang it.