# css (box-shadow) transition on page load

Tags: javascript, css, transition

Is there a way to make a transition happen for a box-shadow on page load instead of with a hover or click effect?

The transition I want on page load, or as an event:

```
.item:hover{
margin:0 auto;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px  grey;
transition: 0.7s;
max-width: 940px;
color: dimgrey;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

Comment: have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679567/using-css-for-a-fade-in-effect-on-page-load

Comment: yes, i was a bit tired and think i thought the keyframes was only for movement and colour change, not for like creating a box-shadow onpageyoffset = 900 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. you can name `keyframes` a name and provide the time you need, I have provided`4sec` in the example.
> 2. It says change the background color from `red` to `yellow` and increase the `height` by `200px` and animate this for 4 seconds.

```css
.item {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  animation-name: animate;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@keyframes animate {
  from {
    background-color: red;
  }
  to {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="item">

</div>
```

Comment: how do you make it so that it stays with the end result after finishing?

Comment: I got it, 

animation: animate 1s forwards

the fill node of forwards did it