# All images made visible with the same id after 5 seconds with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a grid of product images and I would like all images with the same ID to be made visible after 5 seconds with javascript. At the moment it only works with the first image while the others remain hidden and all have the same id. I wish it would work for all images with the same ID.

/*html example*/

```
<div class"product1 image">
<img src="image1.jpg" id="myid">
</div>

<div class"product2 image">
<img src="image2.jpg" id="myid">
</div>
```

/*css example*/

```
.image {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

/*js example*/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function change () {
  var image = document.getElementById ("myid");
    image.style.visibility = "visible";
}
setTimeout ("change ();", 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: There can't be multiple elements with the same ID in valid HTML, so this won't work, by design.

Comment: ids should be unique. why not give them the same class

Comment: Never pass a string to `setTimeout`. use `setTimeout(change, 5000);` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should only ever have one element with a particular ID in your page.  `getElementById` returns a single element, so it is likely just finding the first item in the screen.

You could give them either a css class with the same name, or use a data-* attribute to identify them e.g.

```
<img src="image2.jpg" data-image-group="bob" />
```

And this would then return all the elements matching that group name:

```
let matchedImages = document.querySelectorAll("[data-image-group='bob']")

matchedImages .forEach(function(image) {
  image.style.visibility = "visible";
});
```

Alternatively (and this might be the best approach), consider a pure CSS approach to dealing with this display problem and use an animation to have them hidden initially and then fade in.  A sample of this can be found on this answer:

[Using CSS for a fade-in effect on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679567/using-css-for-a-fade-in-effect-on-page-load)

Answer (score 1):

A few issues with your code. First you're missing `=` when setting class of `div`. Then `id`s should be unique. Probably the easiest solution after fixing the minor problems is to use `querySelectorAll` and query `img` that are children of `.image` class which is already set.

```js
function change () {
  var images = document.querySelectorAll(".image img");
    images.forEach(image=>image.style.visibility = "visible");
}
setTimeout (change, 5000);
```

```css
.image {
    visibility: hidden;
}
img{
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product1 image">
<img src="https://logos-download.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/JavaScript_Logo.png">
</div>

<div class="product2 image">
<img src="https://blog.jeremylikness.com/blog/2019-03-05_typescript-for-javascript-developers-by-refactoring-part-1-of-2/images/1.jpeg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

id identifier must be unique and applied on single element. You can't specify same `id` value for more than 1 elements. You can but it wouldn't work and is a poor HTML practice. You should use classes for such cases. You can give `image` class name for all your elements and then select them by class name using JavaScript:

```
<div class="product1 image">
  <img src="image1.jpg" class="image">
</div>

<div class="product2 image">
  <img src="image2.jpg" class="image">
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function change () {
  var images = document.getElementsByClassName("myid");
  images.forEach(element => element.style.visibility = "visible");
}
setTimeout ("change ();", 5000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this script very useful on a per class basis. I have another question about this script! could you add the fade effect to the appearance of the images by embedding this code?

```
function change () {
  var images = document.querySelectorAll(".image img");
    images.forEach(image=>image.style.visibility = "visible");
}
setTimeout (change, 5000);
```