# How do I delay an element?

Tags: css, delay

I have this CSS code but the botton completely dissapears. How do I get it to appear after 5 seconds?

```
div#button-y4sCSuA9ms {
     background-image: linear-gradient(170deg, #ffe259, #ffa751) !important;
     box-shadow: 0 16px 32px 0 rgb(128 99 66 / 25%)  !important;
     color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95)  !important;
     opacity: 0;
     animation: fadeIn 1s;
     animation-delay: 5s;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
     pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: What does the `fadeIn` animation do? (Presumably it affects opacity, but it would be worth including it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you simply forgot to add keyframes for `fadeIn`.
See snippet below, which will fade the button in after 2 seconds (to remove some wait time for you, just kick it back up to 5s):

```css
div#button-y4sCSuA9ms {
     background-image: linear-gradient(170deg, #ffe259, #ffa751) !important;
     box-shadow: 0 16px 32px 0 rgb(128 99 66 / 25%)  !important;
     color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95)  !important;
     opacity: 0;
     animation: fadeIn 1s;
     animation-delay: 2s;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
     pointer-events: none;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div id="button-y4sCSuA9ms">Button text</div>
```

See this StackOverflow answer about CSS transitions and browser compatibility for more information:
[CSS transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11681331/10441671)

Answer (score 0):

By setting

```
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

in the CSS, the animation keeps repeating every 5 seconds (the *animation-delay* property you have set).

If don't want the animation to keep repeating forever, just set the *animation-iteration-count* to a number.

Comment: They wanted to display the element after 5 seconds, not every 5 seconds. The keyframes for fadeIn were simply missing.

Comment: Didn't notice that, thank you for the comment!