# Fade in & out text loop - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have two quotes wrapped in H2 tags that I want to fade in and out using jQuery. When the page loads I want the first quote to fade in, delay for a few seconds and fade out then the next quote to do the same. I would like it to continue to loop through the two quotes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You could do it like this:

CSS:

```
.quotes {display: none;}​
```

HTML:

```
<h2 class="quotes">first quote</h2>
<h2 class="quotes">second quote</h2>​
```

Javascript:

```
// code gets installed at the end of the body (after all other HTML)
(function() {

    var quotes = $(".quotes");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
    }

    showNextQuote();

})();​
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/n4mKw/

This code will work for any number of quotes you have, not just two.  If you have content after the quotes, you will likely want to fix the size of the container the quotes are in so that it doesn't change size as you go from one quote to the next (causing the other page contents to jump around).

Comment: My page is loading blank when I add the script. I have a bunch of other items on the page that are not loading.

Comment: @TylerAlmond - How am I supposed to help you with that question when I can't see what you've done?  Obviously, you have some sort of script or HTML error.  Either post a link to what you've done or look in the error console to see what errors you have so you can fix them.  The concept works when executed properly.  FYI, the script above goes inside `<script>` tags at the end of the `<body>` section of the page.

Comment: Sorry about that. Here is a link to the page I am working on: http://tamedia.ca/marlowe/home.html

Comment: @TylerAlmond - all your content on the page is hidden because `real-body` is `display: none` because your javascript has errors.  You also have a script error in scripts.js.  To start with, remove the line in scripts.js with this: `<!--` on it.  That is HTML, not javascript.

Comment: @TylerAlmond - your content also doesn't have any `.quote` items so the code you added won't do anything.

Comment: I removed the HTML from the script but am still getting the error. I have #real-body set to display: none because I have it fading in onLoad. When I comment out the script you have provided me with I do not get any errors. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @jfriend00 Is there a way to do this without employing `display:none`, because that means screenreaders miss that content. Maybe fadeTo?

Comment: @Christopher - there are ways to do it without `display:none`, but they are more complicated or they lay out differently in the page.  If you have a specific case with specific requirements, I'd suggest you post your own question with your own HTML as that isn't the aim of this question or answer.  FYI, using `.fadeTo()` will leave the quotes at `opacity: 0` so they will each occupy their own space in the page and not be in the same spot.  That can be solved with absolute positioning, but is really the subject of another answer, not this one.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00. I actually asked it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369249/displaynone-on-fading-carousel-breaks-accessibility. I've been using the method you posted above in a number of places and loved it, but with the implementation of the new accessibility requirements on government funded sites in Ontario, it's no longer appropriate.

Comment: Over a year later and still useful, just found on Google. Thanks @jfriend00 ! Upvoted.

Comment: If the code isn't working because it is missing the JQuery keyword in the front. I added the `$` to make it work or you can add `JQuery` also.

Comment: @SiKni8 - That `$` is not required.  As the comment in this code says, this code should be placed at the end of the `<body>` section AFTER all HTML.  One can also use the jQuery `ready()` feature as you edited, but that is not how I wrote my answer and it is not required if the code is placed as recommended.  I have reverted your change.

Comment: Ok thanks. I put it at the beginning and hence it wasn't working.

Comment: I add the same code but fade in fade out effect is not coming.

Comment: @DhavalModi - As you can see in the jsFiddle linked in my answer, the code works fine when properly implemented.  If your implementation is not working, then you will need to figure out what has gone wrong in your particular implementation.  If you want help here, then you should post a new question, include the exact code you're using in the question and hopefully people can then help you figure out what has gone wrong in your code.  There's nothing we can do to help without seeing your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to get the above script working.
First you need to reference the apropriate JQuery Framework, so add this *script* tag either in the **`<head>`** section, or at the end of the `<body>` tag, after all other elements:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
```

Then the main JavaScript MUST go be loaded after the aforementioned `<script>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {

    var quotes = $(".quotes");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
    }

    showNextQuote();

})();
</script>
```