# Fading Text Loop Not Working

Tags: jquery

I found code for a text loop here:

[Fade in & out text loop - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065273/fade-in-out-text-loop-jquery)

It works in that demo, and even if I copy and paste ALL of my code into the jsfiddle, the Jquery works.

When I do it in Dreamweaver, it does NOT work. If I open up an new document and put the information in exactly as it is, it still doesn't work. So I feel like I must be missing something simple.

Here's a link to the page:

http://divingdog.com/_hairofdog/

Here's my code for it:

```
.hours
{
display:none;
float:right;
font-size:20px;
padding-top:5px;
z-index:100000;

}

<div class="hours">
Monday – Thursday: 9 AM – 8 PM
</div>

<div class="hours">
Friday – Saturday: 9 AM – 9 PM (8 PM Jan-Mar)
</div>

<div class="hours">
Sunday: 10 AM – 6 PM
</div>

<script>
(function() {

    var hours = $(".hours");
    var hoursIndex = -1;

    function showNextHours() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        hours.eq(hoursIndex % hours.length)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(2000, showNextHours);
    }

    showNextHours();

})();

</script>
```

The script is at the end of the body tag (inside it), and the CSS is on an external sheet.

The fading text should be showing up to the right of the phone number at the top.

I have no idea why it isn't working. :(

Comment: Please do not ask user users to reverse-engineer external sites. Please post an example of your working code in your question.

Comment: Sorry, here's the CSS:

.hours
{
 display:none;
 float:right;
 font-size:20px;
 padding-top:5px;
 z-index:100000;
 
}

The HTML:

 <div class="hours">
    Monday – Thursday: 9 AM – 8 PM
    </div>
    
    <div class="hours">
    Friday – Saturday: 9 AM – 9 PM (8 PM Jan-Mar)
    </div>
    
    <div class="hours">
    Sunday: 10 AM – 6 PM
    </div>

Comment: And script:

<script>
(function() {

    var hours = $(".hours");
    var hoursIndex = -1;
    
    function showNextHours() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        hours.eq(hoursIndex % hours.length)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(2000, showNextHours);
    }
    
    showNextHours();
    
})();

</script>

Comment: I've posted your comments in the question.

Comment: I adjusted my original post to have the code in it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your missing jquery. Adding this to the top of the page should fix it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well, it did fix the error that you were initially getting ($ is not defined). Now you have a new error: "quoteIndex is not defined". It looks like you're trying to increment the variable "quoteIndex" in the  showNextHours() function but quoteIndex isn't defined. In the example Fade in Out script you link to, quoteIndex is set to -1 (var quoteIndex = -1;) but you renamed that var to hoursIndex in your code. Either change it back, or change quoteIndex to hoursIndex.

Comment: Thanks! That made the text appear in the first div, but it isn't cycling through them.

Comment: You have another error now. Try to troubleshoot it yourself. Using chrome, right click anywhere on the page and select "Inspect Element", then click on the Console tab of the Developer Tools that appear. You will see your (new) error message there and the offending code. Try googling the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Got it to work by linking to the most RECENT version of jquery:

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

The error was caused because delay wasn't supported in the previously linked version.

Thanks for the help! :)