# Fade text loop - not looping, can't see text

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, text, fade

**FYI, this was resolved. [www.WEBCO-MN.com](http://www.WEBCO-MN.com) - scroll to the bottom where it says "What customers are saying..." Thank you for your help!**

I'm new with all this. I know HTML - not a pro. 
I really don't know javascript. I am used to just copying and pasting it. I am trying to create a testimonial section so it will fade from one testimonial to another to another, etc. Once I used the codes I found here:
[Fade in & out text loop - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065273/fade-in-out-text-loop-jquery) , nothing shows up.

Here's a link to the page I'm working on:
http://www.webco-mn.com/webco_test3.html

Here is what I've got going on:
HTML:

```
    <h2 class="quotes">first testimonial</h2>
    <h2 class="quotes">second testimonial</h2>
```

JS:

```
    (function() {

var quotes = $(".quotes");
var quoteIndex = -1;

function showNextQuote() {
    ++quoteIndex;
    quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
        .fadeIn(2000)
        .delay(2000)
        .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
}

showNextQuote();

    })();
```

And CSS:

```
    .quotes {display: none;}​
```

Can somebody please help me figure out what is going on?!
PS - I did NOT design this website, and I have not touched the design HTML part of any of it, I am not that advanced and I don't want to ruin anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use that jQuery code, you need to link to the jQuery javascript library.

In the test page you linked to, you are referencing both the script you want to use and jQuery after the closing html tag:

```
</html>
<script>
(function() {

    var quotes = $(".quotes");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
    }

    showNextQuote();

})();</script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Try adding the reference to jQuery at the end of your `<head>` element, and the script you are trying to use at the end of your `<body>` element.

I would also recommend reading this [basic overview of how jQuery works](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/).

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to SO! If my answer was useful in fixing your problem, you can upvote and/or accept it!