# Display:none on fading carousel breaks accessibility

Tags: jquery, accessibility

I've got a twitter fading carousel type thing going at the bottom of http://seontario.org. It uses display:none to show and hide the tweets. But display:none doesn't work with screen readers because they don't render that content. Any thoughts on how to do this so that it would be accessible?

```
// TWITTER FEED
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var latesttweets = $(".latest-tweets ul li");
var tweetIndex = -1;

function showNextTweet() {
    ++tweetIndex;
    latesttweets.eq(tweetIndex % latesttweets.length)
        .fadeIn(600)
        .delay(8000)
        .fadeOut(400, showNextTweet);
}

showNextTweet();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try

```
height: 0;
width: 0;
overflow: hidden;
```

Or

```
position: fixed;
top: -999999px;
left: -999999px;
```

Comment: fadeIn and fadeOut change the display:none to display:list-item on each li as it cycles. How would I use this?

Comment: You could use classes: in your stylesheet, add `.myclass{ /* styles here */ }`. And then, use `.addClass('myclass')` and `.removeClass('myclass')`

Comment: So, rather than use fadeIn and fadeOut, use addClass and removeClass? How would the showNextTweet function work then, given that removeClass doesn't have that second option? Should I be looking at fadeTo instead?